# brew install すると invalid byte sequence in UTF-8 エラーが出る

Tags: macos, homebrew

MacOSX  
ver 10.12.1

Homebrewがおかしいことが発覚したので再インストールをするつもりでした。  
`brew update`が使えたのでHomebrewは入っているはずなのですが

```
brew install ほにゃらら
```

すると、下記のエラーが出ます。

```
/usr/local/Homebrew/Library/Homebrew/PATH.rb:71:in `split': invalid byte sequence in UTF-8 (ArgumentError)
    from /usr/local/Homebrew/Library/Homebrew/PATH.rb:71:in `block in parse'
    from /usr/local/Homebrew/Library/Homebrew/PATH.rb:71:in `each'
    from /usr/local/Homebrew/Library/Homebrew/PATH.rb:71:in `flat_map'
    from /usr/local/Homebrew/Library/Homebrew/PATH.rb:71:in `parse'
    from /usr/local/Homebrew/Library/Homebrew/PATH.rb:8:in `initialize'
    from /usr/local/Homebrew/Library/Homebrew/utils.rb:310:in `new'
    from /usr/local/Homebrew/Library/Homebrew/utils.rb:310:in `which_all'
    from /usr/local/Homebrew/Library/Homebrew/gpg.rb:5:in `find_gpg'
    from /usr/local/Homebrew/Library/Homebrew/gpg.rb:20:in `gpg2'
    from /usr/local/Homebrew/Library/Homebrew/gpg.rb:23:in `<class:Gpg>'
    from /usr/local/Homebrew/Library/Homebrew/gpg.rb:3:in `<top (required)>'
    from /Library/Ruby/Site/2.0.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:55:in `require'
    from /Library/Ruby/Site/2.0.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:55:in `require'
    from /usr/local/Homebrew/Library/Homebrew/requirements/gpg2_requirement.rb:2:in `<top (required)>'
    from /Library/Ruby/Site/2.0.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:55:in `require'
    from /Library/Ruby/Site/2.0.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:55:in `require'
    from /usr/local/Homebrew/Library/Homebrew/requirements.rb:3:in `<top (required)>'
    from /Library/Ruby/Site/2.0.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:55:in `require'
    from /Library/Ruby/Site/2.0.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:55:in `require'
    from /usr/local/Homebrew/Library/Homebrew/dependency_collector.rb:5:in `<top (required)>'
    from /Library/Ruby/Site/2.0.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:55:in `require'
    from /Library/Ruby/Site/2.0.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:55:in `require'
    from /usr/local/Homebrew/Library/Homebrew/software_spec.rb:7:in `<top (required)>'
    from /Library/Ruby/Site/2.0.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:55:in `require'
    from /Library/Ruby/Site/2.0.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:55:in `require'
    from /usr/local/Homebrew/Library/Homebrew/formula.rb:10:in `<top (required)>'
    from /Library/Ruby/Site/2.0.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:55:in `require'
    from /Library/Ruby/Site/2.0.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:55:in `require'
    from /usr/local/Homebrew/Library/Homebrew/readall.rb:1:in `<top (required)>'
    from /Library/Ruby/Site/2.0.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:55:in `require'
    from /Library/Ruby/Site/2.0.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:55:in `require'
    from /usr/local/Homebrew/Library/Homebrew/tap.rb:2:in `<top (required)>'
    from /Library/Ruby/Site/2.0.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:55:in `require'
    from /Library/Ruby/Site/2.0.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:55:in `require'
    from /usr/local/Homebrew/Library/Homebrew/compat/tap.rb:1:in `<top (required)>'
    from /Library/Ruby/Site/2.0.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:55:in `require'
    from /Library/Ruby/Site/2.0.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:55:in `require'
    from /usr/local/Homebrew/Library/Homebrew/compat.rb:2:in `<top (required)>'
    from /Library/Ruby/Site/2.0.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:55:in `require'
    from /Library/Ruby/Site/2.0.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:55:in `require'
    from /usr/local/Homebrew/Library/Homebrew/global.rb:56:in `<top (required)>'
    from /Library/Ruby/Site/2.0.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:55:in `require'
    from /Library/Ruby/Site/2.0.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:55:in `require'
    from /usr/local/Homebrew/Library/Homebrew/brew.rb:14:in `<main>'
```

ターミナルでrubyコマンドを打ってもずっと反応がないです。確実におかしいのですがどこで異常を確認できますか？ 
brewコマンドは`brew update`以外doctorも含めて上記のエラーがでます。

この投稿はマルチポストです。
https://teratail.com/questions/78714

よろしくお願いします。

Comment: クロスポスト： https://teratail.com/questions/78616

Comment: クロスポスト： https://teratail.com/questions/78714

Comment: スタック・オーバーフローへようこそ！　こちらの質問は、teratailでの質問をそのまま移動してきたもののようですが、あっていますか？　もしそうでしたら、こちらの投稿を一度ご覧ください。 [「マルチポストとはなんですか？」](https://ja.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/2418/19110)

Comment: 質問文中に「前回の質問」とありますが、どの質問のことでしょうか。

Comment: すみません.teratailでの同種です.https：//teratail.com/questions/78601　こちらがその質問になります。マルチポストのルールがわかっておらず申す仕分けございません。

Comment: いえいえ、マルチポストについてのルールは分かりやすいところには書かれていないので、あまり気になさらないでください。ところでエラーログを見る感じだと私は`PATH`変数の中身を疑っているのですが、`echo ${PATH}`の出力に変な文字が混ざっていたりしませんか？　分からなければ、出力をそのままコピペしていただけませんか？

Comment: 色々なホームページを見て編集しているので重複があります内容は以下の通りです  eval "$(rbenv init -)"  
export PATH="$HOME/.pyenv/shims:$PATH"  
export PATH=“/Users/k14044kk/.pyenv/versions/anaconda3-
 4.3.1/envs/opencvtest/lib/python3.5/site-packages/cv2.cpython-35m-darwin.so:$PATH”export PYENV_ROOT="$HOME/.pyenv"  
  export PATH="$PYENV_ROOT/bin:$PATH"  
  export PATH=/usr/local/bin:$PATH  
  export PATH="$HOME/Users/k14044kk/.rbenv/bin:$PATH"  
  export PATH="$HOME/Users/k14044kk/.rbenv/plugins/ruby-build/bin:$PATH"  export PATH="$HOME/.rbenv/bin:$PATH"
  eval "$(rbenv init -)" 改行が行えませんがどうすれば良いでしょうか？

Comment: 質問文の下の方に追記して頂ければ結構です。また、おそらく上のコメントの内容は`~/.bashrc`などに書いているシェルスクリプトだと思うのですが、それではなくてターミナルの上で`echo ${PATH}`したときの出力をそのままコピペして頂けませんか？　公開したくない文字列が含まれている場合は適当に他の文字列で置き換えてください。

Comment: nekketsuuu 様本当にあなたは神様です。どれくらい待っても回答が得られなかったのが嘘のようです。私はbash_profileから不適当な文字列を見つけたのでそれを修正すると見事に全てのコマンドが使うことができるようになりました。あなたは神様です。あのエラーのどこから判断できたのでしょうか。

Comment: 良かったです。マルチポスト先の teratail の方の質問にも回答の情報があると teratail の回答者がいくらか助かるかと思います。よろしくお願いします。判断の仕方に関しては回答に書きましたので、分からないところがあれば回答の方にコメントください。

Comment: 了解です！質問ばかりでてくる毎日ですのでまた頼りたいです。本当に本当にありがとうございました！ちなみにこのサイトベストアンサーや解決済みにする方法はありますでしょうか？？

Comment: 質問の左横にある緑色の旗を押すと質問を承認できます。もっと詳しくは[ヘルプセンター](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/help)をご参照ください。

Answer (score 0, accepted):

エラーの内容が

```
PATH.rb:71:in `split': invalid byte sequence in UTF-8 (ArgumentError)
```

なので、変数 `PATH` の中に UTF-8 として正しくないバイト列が紛れ込んでいるようです。
新しいターミナルで `echo ${PATH}` を実行してその **出力** を見て、中身に変な文字が含まれていないか確認してください。

変な文字が含まれていれば、その部分を `PATH` に追加している設定ファイルが存在するはずなので、そのファイルを探して修正してください。
具体的には、MacOS で bash を使っている場合だとたとえば以下のファイルが怪しいです。

```
/etc/profile
~/.bash_profile
~/.bash_login   (.bash_profile が無い場合)
~/.profile      (.bash_login が無い場合)
~/.bashrc
/etc/paths
/etc/paths.d
```

---

- 関連する投稿

  - [Homebrew and ruby error with UTF-8 and 'split'](https://stackoverflow.com/q/24482265/5989200) -- Stack Overflow
  - [Where does $PATH get set in OS X 10.6 Snow Leopard?](https://superuser.com/q/69130/680903) -- SuperUser
  - [PATH設定がどこにあるか分からないときに見るべきファイル](http://qiita.com/gm_kou/items/24dec9f0e51b9343651b) -- Qiita